# How to avoid rerendering of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have found similiar problems here on stackoverflow, but none brought me to the solution.

I am using react 16.12.0 with Functional Components.
I have this app:

```
const App: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const [value1, setValue1] = useState<number>(1);
    const [value2, setValue2] = useState<boolean>(true);

    function incrementValue1(){
        setValue1(value1+1);
    }

    function sendToServer(){
        ...do something...
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Child value2={value2} sendToServer={sendToServer} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Button variant="outlined"
                            color="primary"
                            size="large"
                            onClick={incrementValue1}>
                        Increment value1
                    </Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Although the parent is changing a value, which is not in the interest of the child component, the child component does rerender every time when the parent component renders.

I read about memo and could incorporate any component into a memo and use the second parameter of memo to tell react when to render. But I'm not sure if that's right. And before I am rewriting a lot of classes I would like to know which way is the correct one.
For example:

```
const Child: React.FC<Props> = React.memo(props) => {
    ...Logic from child component...
},[props.value2])
```

What is the correct way to go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the [React Memo documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

> If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result

So basically, if you wrap the `Child` component into `React.memo`, the component will not re-render if the props don't change over the time

```
// Child component
function Child({value2, sendToServer}) {
  ...
}

export default React.memo(Child);
```

If you want to re-render the `Child` component **only** when the property `value2` is changing, then you can use the second parameter which is a functtion that should return `true` when the component doesn't need to be re-rerendered

So it will be :

```
export default React.memo(
  Child, 
  (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.value2 === nextProps.value2
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should understand, that wrapping all your components with `memo` also will cost some resources. So I recommend you just don't care that much about components being re-rendered, it's not a big problem as long as this re-rendering doesn't affect any "expensive" calculations.

For those(expensive) parts of code, I would recommend you to use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo). So you will use that optimization only where it is actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use plain [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

```js
const Child = React.memo((props) => {
...
});
```

This way the child will skip rerendering if all of its props are equal.

The other change you'll have to do is to wrap your `sendToServer` with [React.useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

```js
const sendToServer = React.useCallback(function() {
...
}, []);
```

The useCallback will keep the reference to `sendToServer` the same accross renders, so the memoization of this Child will work. This is the exact use case why `useCallback` exists.